# Предупреждение: [dcc32 Warning] W1030 Invalid compiler directive: 'true'

Tags: delphi-xe2, delphi, delphi-xe5, delphi-7, delphi-xe

Всем привет! При компиляции выдало предупреждение: [dcc32 Warning] W1030 Invalid compiler directive: 'true'. Работе приложения это не мешает, однако считаю, что "врага надо знать в лицо". Прогуглил - ответа не нашел. Если кто сталкивался, прошу подскажите. Так же был бы очень признателен ссылке на подробное описание подобных сообщений. Заранее всем спасибо:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в коде где-то написано

```
 {$true}
```

Вероятно, вы хотели закомментировать `true`, но доллар затесался. А выражения вида `{$xxx}` компилятор расценивает как директивы. А коль скоро такой директивы нет, он и кидает вам ворнинг.

Comment: @Nofate ♦ Вы гений! А мне учиться, учиться, учиться, учиться..